# The minus and plus buttons work but get stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

The buttons should move a few arrows to the right and left I choose in the check box which arrow I want and then it should move each time + or - 20 degrees so that the breasts rotate.
The buttons work but they get stuck and the arrows do not move smoothly.

curretnAngle is a new angle that I compare to each arrow and its angles and then in the second function I change it to 20 degrees each time

```
  const handleChange=(e)=>{
    let curretnAngle;
    if (props.selectedButton=='turret') {
      console.log(props.selectedButton);
      curretnAngle = props.angleTurret
       console.log(props.angleTurret, curretnAngle);
    }
    else if (props.selectedButton=='lazer') {
       curretnAngle= props.angleLazer
    } 
    else{
      curretnAngle = props.radanglee
    }
   
  
   
    switch (e.target.name){
      case 'minus':
        console.log(curretnAngle,props.selectedButton);
          props.handlerotat(curretnAngle-20)
          console.log('minus')
          break;
        case 'plus':
        console.log(curretnAngle,props.selectedButton);
          props.handlerotate(curretnAngle+20)
          console.log('plus')
          break;
    }
```

```
const handlerotate=(newAngle)=>{
 switch (selectedButton) {
   case 'turret':
     setAngleTurret(newAngle)
     break;
   case 'lazer':
     setAngleLazer(newAngle)
      break;
   case 'lezerr':
     setAnglerad(newAngle)
     break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "getting stuck" and "not moving smoothly"? Can you share a [mcve]? There is not enough information in your question to troubleshoot what could've gone wrong.

Comment: I press right and the arrow moves presses again and the arrow moves again another 20 degrees and so on until suddenly he does not move, he does not get the command of moving 20 degrees, presses and then yes moves, and so it repeats itself